# Что-то делаю неправильно, хелп

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите ошибку, почему не работает код
Код чтобы пройтись по массиву и найти общее число одинаковых слов, которых больше всего

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] Arr = {"abc", "ab", "abcd", "abc", "bla", "blabla", "blablabla", "bla.", "bla,", "bla!"};
    String n = mostFrequent(Arr);
    System.out.println(n);
}

public static String mostFrequent(String [] Arr) {
    String oftGet = "";
    //String [] Arr = {"bla", "bla", "net"};
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Arr.length; j++) {
            if (Arr[i].equals(Arr[j])) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter2 < counter) {
            counter2 = counter;
            oftGet = Arr[i];
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return oftGet;
}
```

Comment: `public static String mostFrequent(string[] Arr) { ... }`

Comment: Да, ты прав, но в задании нужно сделать метод без String [] Arr внутри скобок((

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы неправильно поняли задание. Или там прямо есть такие слова: "сделать метод без String [] Arr внутри скобок"?

Comment: Там есть уже готовые методы, которые нужно дописать. В том и делоб что есть тоже такие методы, где в скобках есть стринг. Вот мне и хотелось бы узнать возможно ли без Стринга внутри скобок?

Comment: Вы используете какую-то свою терминологию, которую я не понимаю.

Comment: Приходится часто на инстранном говорить, что отражается на родном языке. В общем есть методы, которые нужно без ничего в скобках сделать, например, public String mostF(){}, а есть методы, где в скобках что - то уже дано, например, массив - public String mostG(String [] Arr){}. Вот мне и интересно как вызвать методы, где в скобках никакого значения нет, чтобы они правильно работали

Comment: Значит в случае, когда массив не передается как параметр, он должен быть членом класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (counter2 < counter) {
    counter2 = counter;
    oftGet = Arr[i];
}
counter = 0;
```

---

```
static String [] Arr = {"abc", "ab", "abcd", "abc", "bla", "blabla", "blablabla", "bla.", "bla,", "bla!"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String n = mostFrequent();
    System.out.println(n);
}

public static String mostFrequent() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо за доработку) Осталось его правильно вызвать, чтобы работал)

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь)